# Non-resizeable, bordered WPF Windows with WindowStyle=None

Tags: c#, wpf, window, border, aero-glass

Basically, I need a window to look like the following image: http://screenshots.thex9.net/2010-05-31_2132.png

(Is NOT resizeable, yet retains the glass border)

I've managed to get it working with Windows Forms, but I need to be using WPF. To get it working in Windows Forms, I used the following code:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x84 /* WM_NCHITTEST */)
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

This does exactly what I want it to, but I can't find a WPF-equivalent. The closest I've managed to get with WPF caused the Window to ignore any mouse input.

Any help would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: Could you re-phrase the question perhaps, as setting "WindowStyle=None" for a WPF window appears to do exactly what you want e.g. a window with a small glass border which is re-sizable and look just like the screenshot.

Comment: I want the window to be NON-resizeable but retain the glass border. I made that quite clear in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a hook for the message loop :

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    var hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(interopHelper.Handle);
    hwndSource.AddHook(WndProcHook);
}

private IntPtr WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == 0x84 /* WM_NCHITTEST */)
    {
         handled = true;
         return (IntPtr)1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution is to set the Min and Max size of each window equal to each other and to a fix number in the window constructor. just like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MinWidth = this.MaxWidth = 300;
    this.MinHeight = this.MaxHeight = 300;
}
```

this way the user can not change the width and height of the window. also you must set the "WindowStyle=None" property in order the get the glass border.